# Transfer content from one Alfresco instance to another (same version) on another server

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

What would be the best /better way to transfer repository content from one Alfresco (enterprise edition) to another instance running on a different server. Currently we copy the entire Alfresco database & file system under alf_data but that needs a down time on the servers.

I would require a mechanism without down time & the repository data be copied from one instance to another. Is there any way this is possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Heiko's solution, you might be interested in:

- The out-of-the-box [replication service](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/admintools-replication-config.html), which wouldn't be good for replicating your entire repo, but can be used for replicating a handful of nodes from one server to another.
- A [solution from Parashift](https://www.parashift.com.au/2016/04/18/stream-processing-alfresco/) which allows one- and two-way replication of nodes between servers.
- An [Alfresco presentation](https://summit.alfresco.com/cmis/views/workspace%25253A%25252F%25252FSpacesStore%25252F512cc225-8a50-4ab1-a352-de5a705f50d9) on using Apache Camel and Apache Kafka to replicate nodes between servers. This is available through Alfresco's professional services organization, but it may make it into the product at some point. Or you could use it as inspiration to write your own solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that @Jeff ! Exactly what I was looking for. But landed into another problem now :( The 2nd server we had setup was a clone of the 1st one. Now it has the same Repostiory ID as the first one. Checked Alfresco forum & learnt that the repository ID cannot be changed. Looks like wiping out the 2nd server & doing a fresh installation and setup the replication is the only way to do.

Comment: Update: Did a fresh installation & we were able to replicate the content successfully. Prerequisite is repository ID's for the 2 instances should be different for the replication to work. Thanks a ton @jeff-potts !

Answer (score 1):

What is your intention? A standby system, a real copy, an external private cloud with a subset of data?
If you just need a 100% clone you can script backup & restore without downtime on the source server. Downtime is limited to the db and index restore on the target system. Your script shouldn't copy life data from solr index - use the backup done by the solr backup job instead. Depending on the database you use online db backup shouldn't be an issue.
Our [Alfresco Virtual Appliance](https://summit.alfresco.com/barcelona/sessions/alfresco-virtual-appliance) has preconfigured scripts and jobs for this task to start an additional alfresco instance from snapshot backups without copying the contentstore (we call this Alfresco Time Machine).

If your aim is an external private cloud server or a road warrior solution [ecm4u](http://www.ecm4u.de) has a commercial alfresco module to sync very efficient a subset of modified nodes including metadata/types/aspects (list of types and aspects needs to be defined). This sync provides a REST interface for automation and also manual execution from alfresco's admin console. We support mix of alfreso versions and editions. At the moment this sync is implemented as a unidirectional sync but could be extended as a bidirectional sync.

Comment: Our intention is to have a real copy of one environment in another environment. One of the environment is created earlier & up and running with a initial set of data. The next environment was setup recently and for some reason we need to have both the environments up and running. One of the environment will be having the content created by users which has to be synced to the another one on a daily basis. I don't mind having the Solr index recreated. What I need is the metadata and documents created from the source system with minimal or zero down time. Possible ?

Comment: Sure. The Backup/Recovery approach means a downtime for the database restore on the target. If you want to avoid the downtme at all you need to sync content. If you need to keep metadata you could use our module "ecm4u Alfresco Sync" otherwise you could use any sync tool like rsync against Alfresco's file protocols.

Comment: So you mean to say for Alfresco content documents its just enough to sync the file system data under alf_data folder ? Is it under contentstore directory ? Suppose if my document is of a custom type, if I sync the folder to target system, will it still retain the same type (assuming the custom model is present on the target server as well). No need of any DB sync at all in this case (if it has to be only documents) ?

Comment: No - I meant the Alfresco virtual filesystem abstraction. You can mount both alfresco systems using webdav or CIFS and then sync the folder hierarchy of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this task of installing 2 alfresco instances on my local running on 2 different ports.
While performing some tasks, I realized that 2 instances having same Repository ID is creating issues.
I was able to change the repository ID of one of them following below steps:

- update `alfresco-global.properties`:

  ```
  db.name="Add new DB Name"
  ```

  (Alfresco will create a db db.name mentioned here while initializing)
- and restart the server

If you are still facing issues, try deleting `solr` indexes under `alf-data` folder.

Comment: This will bootstrap a new alfresco repo with `db.name` on the same database server for your second local instalation (not just rename the repository ID). You should also remove the content in your alf_data/contentstore having the renamed db since this content is no longr referenced.