# Alfresco selective content synchronization to another instance

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

In continuation with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390566/transfer-content-from-one-alfresco-instance-to-another-same-version-on-another), I would like to selectively choose documents from my repository and then sync them to a target repository. If possible lets say choose the documents in a folder, click on Selected Items menu dropdown & have a custom menu item say "Publish" and the action defined on that menu item should be publish to a pre-defined target repository. Possible ? I'm open to customizing with webscripts. A little help on the services I need to use would be good as am a novice to Alfresco customization.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I find the out-of-the-box replication service to be unreliable to the point of not being usable for even moderate use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback @JeffPotts we're using Alfresco One 5.1. Is there any plugins / options available for the commercial edition ?

Comment: Yes, I gave you a list on your other post regarding this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390566/transfer-content-from-one-alfresco-instance-to-another-same-version-on-another

Comment: Ah great. Yes I did read through them. Will take it forward. Thanks a lot @JeffPotts

Answer (score 0):

Altough I am not answering your question completely, I would like to share my idea.

I have been looking for a way to invoke a replication job from Script (not Webscript). Have a look at this question [How to start an FTR Replication Job from Alfresco Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923391/how-to-start-an-ftr-replication-job-from-alfresco-script)

So, providing you know how to customize the Share menu with .amp and the rest, I think you can start working on the second option I am mentioning in the question, to selectively choose which nodes you want to transfer:

```
var nodes = // your array of ScriptNodes
transfer.transfer('MyTargetName', nodes);
```

Hope this helps...